# Задать срабатывание скрипта только на текущем элементе

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, carousel

Есть код для пролистывания слайдов стрелками на клавиатуре:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        // Previous
        $(".carousel-control-prev").click();
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        // Next
        $(".carousel-control-next").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Как можно модифицировать этот скрипт, чтобы он срабатывал только на текущей карусели, а не на всех каруселях на странице?

Comment: добавить нужной карусели id и в селекторе вместо класса обращаться к id?

Comment: а как вы определяете текущую карусель?

Comment: не поняла как определить текущую карусель, поэтому сделала через классы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению более универсального решения не нашла, сделала так:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        // Previous
        $('.js-control-modal-gallery-photos .carousel-control-prev').click();
        $('.js-control-photo-gallery .carousel-control-prev').click();
        $('.js-control-gallery-team .carousel-control-prev').click();
        $('.js-control-gallery-customers .carousel-control-prev').click();
        $('.js-control-jobs .carousel-control-prev').click();
        $('.js-control-tech-list .carousel-control-prev').click();
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        // Next
        $('.js-control-modal-gallery-photos .carousel-control-next').click();
        $('.js-control-photo-gallery .carousel-control-next').click();
        $('.js-control-gallery-team .carousel-control-next').click();
        $('.js-control-gallery-customers .carousel-control-next').click();
        $('.js-control-jobs .carousel-control-next').click();
        $('.js-control-tech-list .carousel-control-next').click();
        return false;
    }
});
```